# Mobile website redirection based on user agent

Tags: .htaccess, mobile, web, dns, redirect

Say I've got two distinct domains:

```
 1) http://sub.test.org
 2) http://m.sub.test.org
```

for my website.

I want domain n.1 to be associated to the full-version of my website (intended to be mainly visited by desktop user agents) and domain n.2 to be associated to its mobile-version (intended to be mainly visited by mobile user agents).

Both of the versions reside on an external host which runs an instance of Apache webserver I can't control directly, but I am able to post `.htaccess` files and therefore I want them to control domain redirecting stuff (I don't want to use Javascript neither PHP server-side logic)

The directory structure on the external host is, say:

```
directory / --> contains full-version website's pages and resources 
                (index.html is the entry-point)

directory /mobile --> contains full-version website's pages and resources 
                      (index.html is the entry-point)
```

and the mappings are:

```
http://sub.test.org -> /index.html
http://m.sub.test.org -> /mobile/index.html
```

Now, my desired scenarios are as follows:

A) When user asks for URL `http://sub.test.org`:

1. IF current URL is `http://m.sub.test.org/*` (this means: if user is currently into the mobile-version) THEN serve page `http://sub.test.org/index.html`
2. ELSE:

   1. IF user agent is mobile THEN redirect to URL `http://m.sub.test.org`
   2. ELSE serve page `http://sub.test.org/index.html`

B) When user asks for URL `http://m.sub.test.org` - no matter what the user agent is - user should be redirected to URL `http://sub.test.org`.

My questions:

- What would be the syintax of the associated `.htaccess` file?
- Do I need more than one?
- Where should I place it/them ?

Any help/code hint would be really appreciated, because I have really a few experience with Apache `.htaccess` files and regexps! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html
- You would most likely need 2
- place one it in the root and one in /mobile