# wordpress homepage only mobile redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I have viewed a few questions here

[Mobile Redirect using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess)

[Redirection for Mobile using .htaccess - only on homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807250/redirection-for-mobile-using-htaccess-only-on-homepage)

I know its been answered before but I tried to implement what I found with no luck.

I would like to know how to redirect mobile users only for the homepage of my wordpress site through .htaccess

I need users from mobile to be redirected ONLY for the home page www.mysite.com to www.mysite.com/mobilehome. All other pages have to stay the same for mobile and desktop.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't use `wp_is_mobile()` and `wp_redirect()` instead?

Comment: Because of the caching system which interferes with that process. Using it directly from htaccess would make me able to leave my caching configuration as is which is optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After alot of searching and tests I found the solution:

```
# BEGIN Mobile redirect
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/mobile-url [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END Mobile redirect
```